# Проверка заполнения input и radio group

Tags: jquery

Есть форма, как проверить, что заполнена хотя бы одна из радио кнопок и интуп?

```js
    $("form").on("click", "#send_webinar", function (event) {
      if($("input[name='name']").val()!="" && $("input[name='group']").prop("checked")){
        alert("access");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="one">1
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="two">2
  <input type="radio" name="group" value="three">3
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" id="send_webinar" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: `$("input[name='group']:checked").length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

Субъективно: поменьше JS.

HTML5 позволяет вам использовать атрибут: `required` или `required=""`. Скажете браузер может быть старым и не поддерживать HTML5, так и JS может быть выключен.

[Подробнее](https://webref.ru/html/input/required)

Comment: сафари раньше не хавал required вообще. Ситуация поменялась ?